# Using ggplot function in a for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, pdf

I'm trying to build a `for` loop using the `ggplot` function.

I have 204 subjects that were measured 104 times on a scale from 1 to 6.

I would like to print for each subject a separate graph showing the trajectory over those 104 times and save ideally 10 graphs or so on one PDF page.

So the data frame looks like this in wide format:

```
data <- 1:6
ID <- 1:204
T1 <- sample(data, 204, replace = TRUE)
T2 <- sample(data, 204, replace = TRUE)
T3 <- sample(data, 204, replace = TRUE)
T4 <- sample(data, 204, replace = TRUE)
## ...
T104 <- sample(data, 204, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(ID, T1, T2, T3, T4, ..., T104)
```

In long format, the data frame has 21528 observations of 3 variables: `ID`, `time`, and `value` (in `1:6`).

If I use the `ggplot` function for all variables simultaneously, it looks like below:

```
ggplot(data_long,
       aes(x = time,
           y = value,
           col = ID, 
           group = ID)) + 
  geom_line(na.rm = TRUE, size = 1.5)
```

From googling, I created the code below, but it throws an error and doesn't include saving the plots in a PDF:

```
gg_ID <- list(data_long$ID)

for (i in 1:length(gg_ID)) {
  plot <- ggplot(data = gg_ID[[i]], aes(x = time, y = value, col = ID, group = ID)) + 
    geom_line(na.rm = TRUE, size = 1.5)) +
    xlab("time point") +
    ylab("score") +
    ggtitle(names(gg_ID)[i]) +
    geom_text(aes(label = score), vjust = -0.3, color = "black", size = 3.5) +
  print(plot)
}
```

The error is:

> Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a character vector.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work". Did you create a graphics device to save the plots? Or where are you trying to save them? There's a [chapter on arranging plots](https://ggplot2-book.org/arranging-plots.html) in the ggplot book. Have you looked at that to get multiple plots on a page?

Comment: Running the code above returns the following error message: 
"Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a character vector"
Thanks for the chapter recommendation. I just read it and I understand how I would do it if I build single graphs without a loop but not within a loop.